# Boolean Operators in Python

Tags: python

Why can't i do this?

```
extout = os.path.splitext(args.outputfile)[1].lower()
if extout != (".csv" | ".xml"):  # <------- creates error
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: Invalid extension or none found. This program only recognizes .csv or .xml extensions %s\n')
        sys.exit(1)
```

This gives me an type error:

```
Unsupported operand types for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a tuple and `not in`:

```
if extout not in  (".csv", ".xml"):
```

This will return `True` if `extout` doesn't matches any of the tuple items otherwise `False`.

`|` is an Bitwise OR operator in python that's why it is not working on strings.

Comment: That is the proper answer, and Pythonic.

Comment: According the the [optimizations](http://docs.python.org/3.4/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations) made in Python 3.2, you should write `if extout not in  {".csv", ".xml"}:` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do what you want is:

```
if extout not in ('.csv', '.xml'):
    ...
```

Comment: Another pythonic answer. Upvote goes to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

```
if extout != ".csv" and extout != ".xml":
```

which can be shortened to

```
if '.csv' != extout != '.xml':
```

or, of course:

```
if not (extout == '.csv' or extout == '.xml'):
```

or use regexp, then you can use your favored `|` symbol:

```
if re.match(r'\.(csv|xml)$', extout):
```

Answer (score -1):

To test if something is not either of two values, use `in`, as follows :

```
if extout not in (".csv", ".xml"):
   # Do Something.
```

**Extra Note**

`|` is bitwise OR. It cannot be applied to strings. You're looking for the boolean `or`.

```
>>> 'abc' | 'def'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    'abc' | 'def'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

>>> 'abc' or 'def'
'abc'
```

The `or` returns `'abc' because of short circuiting.

Comment: -1 No, `".csv" or ".xml"` just evaluates to `".csv"`.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed that. Added it as an extra note instead of the main answer.

Comment: Great, downvote removed.

Comment: But that or I suspect does not do the test the user wants

Comment: I gave the user the answer. That was just an extra note, because he gave us the `TypeError` because of `|`.

Comment: Can all the downvoters please leave a reason? I'd really like to know what is wrong with this answer.